# Highcharts - How to Make the legend item width half of the contianer?

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I have a very long text of a legend item, I know there is a key :itemWidth can set the width,but it can only be the number. but my chart is inside a resizable div, so the width can be changed. it there a way to set the itemWidth half of the container on chart size changing?

[image]

I want it always aligned with 2 columns like this:

[image]

I want the item inside the legend area, it's width should be 50% of the legend area (there is a property itemWidth, but it can only be a number).

Answer (score 0):

Set the `legend.width: '50%'` should resolve your issue.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hft7961a/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.width

Comment: thanks for your comment, but I mean itemWidth(legend item inside the legend area) not the whole width.

Comment: @jjzjx118_2 I see, try this approach: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ym284qo7/